# Compiling fails on Dl_Info

Tags: android, gcc, makefile, gnustep

I am trying to use Android NDK Make to build a project but I get the following errors.

```
In file included from /home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/objc-load.m:44:0:
/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/dynamic-load.h: In function '__objc_dynamic_get_symbol_path':
/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/dynamic-load.h:127:3: error: unknown type name 'Dl_info'
/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/objc-load.m: In function 'GSPrivateSymbolPath':
/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/objc-load.m:263:2: error: unknown type name 'Dl_info'
make: *** [/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/obj/local/armeabi/objs/gnumake/objc-load.o] Error 1
```

I am assuming this is coming from dlfcn.h but it isn't like I am getting a file not found so I am guessing it is loading...

1.) Is the problem in dlfcn.h?
2.) any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify android platform version using `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` in Application.mk. By default if uses android-3 and fails with such error

Comment: Thanks, this solved! This andwer should be accepted:)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it, can't remember exactly what I did but I think it had to do with a linux header I was using as opposed to the Android one I was compiling for.